# How to create a .rar file using python?

Tags: python, rar

I want to create a `.rar` file by passing file paths of the files to be archived.

I have tried the `rarfile` package. But it doesn't have a `'w'` option to write to the rarfile handler.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about [`lib-rar-python`](https://github.com/miebach/lib-rar-python)?

It's a Python wrapper around the command line `rar` program, but it may be limited to Linux only.

On other platforms you could just call the command line rar program directly using Python's [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library.

Comment: It's limited to Linux only. Is there anything for mac?

Comment: Added approach for non-Linux platforms.

Comment: Why is this limited to Linux? It seems that one just needs to install the `rar` command line program, and make sure to pass it's path it as the `rarbin` argument when creating an `Archive` object. This could even work on Windows, as long as you manage to install a `rar` executable which accepts the same set of parameters. See [the code](https://github.com/miebach/lib-rar-python/blob/3db7d2506c99ffd3a94b4ff71ae92197c90fc11f/librar/archive.py) for details.

Answer (score 9):

`os.system('rar a <archive_file_path> <file_path_to_be_added_to_archive>')`

Can also be used to achieve this.

Comment: Te ganaste el cielo, gracias!