# Appending a file to rarfile

Tags: python, zip, rar

How can I write to a `.rar` file in Python? Is there any way to add a file to an existing `.rar` file?

I know how to do this with `.zip` archives. I am looking how to do this with `.rar` archives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a .rar file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31261879/how-to-create-a-rar-file-using-python)